# Automatic .ToString()?

Tags: c#, .net, interface, tostring

I have a method like this: `void m1(string str)` and have a class like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public bool b1 { set; get; }

    //and other properties
}
```

Now why following code does not cause compile error?

```
IClass2 _class2 = new Class2();
MyClass c1 = new MyClass();
_class2.m1("abcdef" + c1);
```

When I debug it, I realized that `c1.ToString()` has been passed to `m1`. Why this automatic `.ToString()` has been occurred? The only thing I could say is that m1 has been defined in `IClass2` interface and has been implemented by `Class2`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This follows the rules of the C# language specification around string concatenation. See section 7.8.4 of the C# 4 spec (the addition operator)

> **String concatenation:**
>
> ```
> string operator +(string x, string y);
> string operator +(string x, object y);
> string operator +(object x, string y);
> ```
>
> These overloads of the binary `+` operator perform string concatenation. If an operand of string concatenation is`null`, an empty string is substituted. Otherwise, any non-string argument is converted to its string representation by invoking the virtual `ToString` method inherited from type object. If `ToString` returns `null`, an empty string is substituted.

If you didn't expect that to happen, may I ask what you expected the result of the `"abcdef" + c1` expression to be?

Note that `m1`, `IClass2` and `Class2` are irrelevant to what's happening here - it's only the concatenation expression which is really relevant: that's what's triggering the call to `ToString()`, regardless of what's later happening to that string.

Comment: It was happened during a project wide change. c1 originally was string. When I changed it's type, I expected a compiler error.

Comment: @afsharm: Ah, right. No, C# has always behaved this way (as does Java).

Answer (score 6):

The compiler turns `"abcdef" + c1` into a `string.Concat(object,object)` call. This in turn will call `.ToString()` on each of the arguments and concatenate them. Here's the code from reflector:

```
public static string Concat(object arg0, object arg1)
{
   if(arg0 == null) arg0 = Empty;
   if(arg1 == null) arg1 = Empty;

   return (arg0.ToString() + arg1.ToString());
}
```

Note that the last line involves a call to `string.Concat(string, string)` where the *real* concatenation happens.