# How do I convert an Int to a String in C# without using ToString()?

Tags: c#, string, algorithm, int

> Convert the following int argument into a string without using any native toString functionality.
>
> ```
> public string integerToString(int integerPassedIn){    
>     //Your code here
> }
> ```

Since everything inherits from `Object` and `Object` has a `ToString()` method how would you convert an `int` to a `string` without using the native `ToString()` method?

The problem with string concatenation is that it will call `ToString()` up the chain until it hits one or hits the `Object` class.

How do you convert an integer to a string in C# without using `ToString()`?

Comment: Iterate over the int mod 10, and concatenate them into new strings seems like it is what they are looking for, but you said concatenation calls toString?

Comment: `String str = "" + a;` would call toString on a i think is what @AMR means

Comment: @Gray Yes, if you use concatenation eventually it will call a toString function.

Comment: Even if you are concatenating two strings? That doesn't make much sense. I could see if you do what @bizzehdee said, but I'd think string concatenations have no reason to call ToString().

Comment: We are not connecting two strings. If a non-string type is concatinated with a string it calls toString. Check the first answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759343/automatic-tostring @Gray

Comment: I think you misunderstand me then, I was talking about concatenating strings as seen in p.s.w.g.'s answer, except, it could just be an array of strings rather than chars.

Comment: StringBuilder.Append((char)((a % 10) + '0'))

Comment: This interview question is interesting not only because the candidate can demonstrate if he is able to come up with an algorithm for converting an int to a string without simply calling `123.ToString()`. At some point in the algorithm the candidate will have to create a string, perhaps from characters, and the function used might be named `ToString`. Candidates that are obsessed about the name `ToString` instead of solving the real problem at hand will be easier to identify.

Comment: Someone had to implement ToString *without calling ToString*. How do you suppose they did it?

Comment: Dark magic... Or @EricLippert did it...

Comment: @EricLippert Got me curious, this blog post is pretty interesting. http://technotes-bipan.blogspot.com/2008/08/boxing-unboxing-in-c.html

Comment: @AMR Why are you asking this question? Was it an interview/homework question, or are you just curious?

Comment: this has turned into int to string code golf in c#

Comment: Would this not work easily?
`int MyInt = 25;
MyStringBuilder.AppendFormat("{0:C} ", MyInt);`

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Something like this:

```
public string IntToString(int a)
{    
    var chars = new[] { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };
    var str = string.Empty;
    if (a == 0)
    {
        str = chars[0];
    }
    else if (a == int.MinValue)
    {
        str = "-2147483648";
    }
    else
    {
        bool isNegative = (a < 0);
        if (isNegative)
        {
            a = -a;
        }

        while (a > 0)
        {
            str = chars[a % 10] + str;
            a /= 10;
        }

        if (isNegative)
        {
            str = "-" + str;
        }
    }

    return str;
}
```

---

**Update:** Here's another version which is shorter and should perform much better, since it eliminates all string concatenation in favor of manipulating a fixed-length array. It supports bases up to 16, but it would be easy to extend it to higher bases. It could probably be improved further:

```
public string IntToString(int a, int radix)
{
    var chars = "0123456789ABCDEF".ToCharArray();
    var str = new char[32]; // maximum number of chars in any base
    var i = str.Length;
    bool isNegative = (a < 0);
    if (a <= 0) // handles 0 and int.MinValue special cases
    {
        str[--i] = chars[-(a % radix)];
        a = -(a / radix);
    }

    while (a != 0)
    {
        str[--i] = chars[a % radix];
        a /= radix;
    }

    if (isNegative)
    {
        str[--i] = '-';
    }

    return new string(str, i, str.Length - i);
}
```

Comment: I was about to write something truly filthy, but this is a lot better

Comment: libc's itoa written in C#, was in the middle of writing this myself when i saw this pop up, nicely done :)

Comment: Very nice. Thanks for the awesome answer.

Comment: @p.s.w.g: im actually in the middle of writing a FOSS common library for C#, would you mind if i used this as part of my lib with a link to either this question or your profile in the comments?

Comment: Nice answer. Small bug though: it crashes on `int.MinValue`

Comment: @Daniel It crashes in a checked context.  In an unchecked context it just prints `-`.

Comment: Wouldn't the character concatenation call the `ToString()` method under the covers?

Comment: Oh and I just realized, this technically still calls `ToString()`, as concatenating a `char` with a `string` will use the `string.Concat(object, object)` overload which calls `ToString` on its arguments.
But that's easy to fix by using an array of strings instead.

Comment: Yeah this answer still doesn't work. Check answer one here for the explanation why http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759343/automatic-tostring

Comment: @AMR using array of strings instead of `var chars` will solve the problem

Comment: @bizzehdee Sure thing, but it could *definitely* be improved further.

Comment: @AMR why you marked this as answer if it's not working for your case?

Comment: because I realized I didn't know what I was commenting about. His type of concatenation is fine.

Comment: I'm really curious, why other than the purpose of the question would you want/need to do this?

Comment: @RyanMcDonough No reason that I can think of, but some of the techniques used here can be helpful elsewhere. For example, understanding how to iterate through an integer's digits has a variety of applications.

Comment: @AMR : The other answer you are talking about @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759343/automatic-tostring is ToString() related, where your original question was about not to use it ... Somehow I am bit confused on your real need !

Comment: @SebastienThuilliez I wasn't saying that the referenced answer was correct I was saying the explanation that it gave was why string concatination invokes toString(); it was just an explanation, not a solution

Comment: Sadly, my edit was rejected, so I comment here:
The above code lacks error checking (for brevity), however, the author claims it works for all radices up to 16, when in fact unary does not work.
Users will need to subtract 1 from a after each division statement when (radix == 1).

Comment: @FRob For unary you can just use `new String("1", a)`, I didn't feel this was significant enough to include here.

Comment: Well, unary would be zeros here, but I see your point. It just irked me that the code wasn't complete ;)

Comment: FYI: You don't need to worry with converting letters to char array as .NET string can be accessed as char array without any conversion, eg. string or var pattern = "abc"; you can access as characters array: pattern[0] will be 'a' of char type. Good luck!

Answer (score 23):

This is the solution I always use:

```
    public static string numberBaseChars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    public static string IntToStringWithBase(int n, int b) {
        return IntToStringWithBase(n, b, 1);
    }

    public static string IntToStringWithBase(int n, int b, int minDigits) {
        if (minDigits < 1) minDigits = 1;
        if (n == 0) return new string('0', minDigits);
        string s = "";
        if ((b < 2) || (b > numberBaseChars.Length)) return s;
        bool neg = false;
        if ((b == 10) && (n < 0)) { neg = true; n = -n; }
        uint N = (uint)n;
        uint B = (uint)b;
        while ((N > 0) | (minDigits-- > 0)) {
            s = numberBaseChars[(int)(N % B)] + s;
            N /= B;
        }
        if (neg) s = "-" + s;
        return s;
    }
```

This looks quite complicated but has the following features:

- Supports radix 2 to 36
- Handles negative values
- Optional total number of digits

Comment: Wait a second, you actually have a real-world use for this?

Comment: @JohnBuchanan: Sure! One example: we have ID-Chips that has unique values. We handle the values as string using radix 36, which are always 8 characters long: `0016I2WM`. This is, as far is i know, not possible with any `.ToString()`. Are there better ways?

Answer (score 10):

I am not truly convinced the concatenation `operator +` calls `ToString`, but if that is indeed true, you can avoid those two by doing something like the following:

```
if (a == 0) return "0";   

/* Negative maxint doesn't have a corresponding positive value, so handle it
 * as a special case. Thanks to @Daniel for pointing this out.
 */
if (a == 0x80000000) return "-2147483648";

List<char> l = new List<char>();
bool negative = false;

if (a < 0) 
{
    negative = true;
    a *= -1;
}

while (a > 0)
{
    l.Add('0' + (char)(a % 10));
    a /= 10;
}

if (negative) l.Add('-');

l.Reverse();

return new String(l.ToArray());
```

Comment: The `+` operator calls `ToString` for one of the overloads in which an operand is of type `object`.  When both operands are of type string it does not.

Comment: @Servy Ok, that's what I thought. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 5):

The integer is processed from the least significant digit to the most significant. A single digit is computed used modulo 10 (%10) which is then added to the character value of '0'. This results in one of the characters '0', '1', ... , '9'.

The digits are pushed onto a stack because they have to be presented in the reverse order as they are processed (most significant digit to least significant digit). Doing it like this instead of repeatedly prepending the digits to a string could be more efficient but because the number of digits is quite low you would have to perform a benchmark to be sure.

Some extra processing is required to handle non-positive numbers.

```
public string IntToString(int a) {
  if (a == 0)
    return "0";
  if (a == int.MinValue)
    return "-2147483648";
  var isNegative = false;
  if (a < 0) {
    a = -a;
    isNegative = true;
  }
  var stack = new Stack<char>();
  while (a != 0) {
    var c = a%10 + '0';
    stack.Push((char) c);
    a /= 10;
  }
  if (isNegative)
    stack.Push('-');
  return new string(stack.ToArray());
}
```

My first version used a `StringBuilder` to create the string from the array of characters but getting the string "out of the" `StringBuilder` requires a call to method named `ToString`. Obviously, this method does not do any int to string conversion which to me is what this question is about.

But to prove that you can create a string without calling `ToString` I have switched to using a `string` constructor which I also would assume to be more efficient compared to using a `StringBuilder`.

And if `ToString` in any form is prohibited you cannot use string concatenation as seen in the documentation for [`string.Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbseaaft.aspx):

> The method concatenates arg0 and arg1by calling the parameterless ToString method of arg0 and arg1; it does not add any delimiters.

so executing `s += '1'` will call `'1'.ToString()`. But to me this isn't important. The important part is how you convert an int to a string.

Comment: Is using a ToString on a StringBuilder against the rules? The alternative is just to use string += string.

Comment: I would imagine so, since StringBuilder is part of the framework. I'm not the OP though :)

Comment: I have now switched away from using `ToString` to satisfy the commenters and even provided an answer that doesn't use `ToString` as string concatenation does behind the scenes.

Answer (score 4):

you can convert any digit to a char like this

```
byte = (char)(byte)(digit+48)
```

The magic number `48` is the ASCII value of the char `0` and they are sequential in the ASCII table thus you can just add the digit to get the corresponding value in the ASCII table.
and you can get the digits in the integer iteratively using the modulus operator `%`
Borrowing the general structure from pswg you would get

```
public string IntToString(int a) {
  var str = string.Empty;
    bool isNegative = false;
    if (a < 0) {
        isNegative = true;
        a = -a;
    }

    do {
        str = (char)(byte)((a % 10) + 48) + str;
        a /= 10;
    } while(a > 0);

    return isNegative ? '-' + str : str
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Aiming for a shorter version, and one that uses `Math.DivRem`:

```
string IntToString(int a)
{
    if (a == int.MinValue)
        return "-2147483648";
    if (a < 0)
        return "-" + IntToString(-a);
    if (a == 0)
        return "0";
    var s = "";
    do
    {
        int r;
        a = Math.DivRem(a, 10, out r);
        s = new string((char)(r + (int)'0'), 1) + s;
    }
    while (a > 0);
    return s;
}
```

The use of the `new string(..., 1)` constructor is just a way to satisfy the OP's requirement that `ToString` not be called on anything.

Answer (score 3):

Here are my takes on it using iteration and recursion with run time analysis.

```
public static class IntegerToString
{
    static char[] d = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray();

    public static string Iteration(int num, int radix = 10)
    {
        if (num == 0) return "0";
        if (num < 0) return "-" + Iteration(Math.Abs(num));
        var r = new List<char>();
        while (num > 0)
        {
            r.Insert(0, d[num % radix]);
            num /= radix;
        }
        return new string(r.ToArray());
    }

    public static string Recursion(int num, int radix = 10)
    {
        if (num == 0) return "0";
        if (num < 0) return "-" + Recursion(Math.Abs(num));
        return (num > radix - 1 ? Recursion(num / radix) : "") + d[num % radix];
    }
}
```

#### Key Points

- Handles base 2 up to 36 (**CAVEAT:** you'll have to ensure your base is correct since there is no exception handling.
- Recursion method is only 3 lines long! (code golf style)

#### Analysis

The following is the runtime analysis of both methods compared to the standard `ToString()` on my computer.

```
50 runs of 100000 items per set

Running Time:
Iteration: 00:00:02.3459591 (00:00:00.0469191 avg)
Recursion: 00:00:02.1359731 (00:00:00.0427194 avg)
Standard : 00:00:00.4271253 (00:00:00.0085425 avg)

Ratios:
     | Iter | Rec  | Std
-----+------+------+-----
Iter | 1.00 | 0.91 | 0.18
Rec  | 1.10 | 1.00 | 0.20
Std  | 5.49 | 5.00 | 1.00
```

The results indicate the iteration and recursion methods run 5.49 and 5.00 times slower than the standard `ToString()` method.

And here is the code I used for the analysis:

```c#
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var r = new Random();
        var sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

        var loop = new List<long>();
        var recr = new List<long>();
        var std = new List<long>();
        var setSize = 100000;
        var runs = 50;

        Console.WriteLine("{0} runs of {1} items per set", runs, setSize);

        for (int j = 0; j < runs; j++)
        {
            // create number set
            var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, setSize)
                                    .Select(s => r.Next(int.MinValue,
                                                        int.MaxValue))
                                    .ToArray();

            // loop
            sw.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < setSize; i++)
                IntegerToString.Iteration(numbers[i]);
            sw.Stop();
            loop.Add(sw.ElapsedTicks);

            // recursion
            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < setSize; i++)
                IntegerToString.Recursion(numbers[i]);
            sw.Stop();
            recr.Add(sw.ElapsedTicks);

            // standard
            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < setSize; i++)
                numbers[i].ToString();
            sw.Stop();
            std.Add(sw.ElapsedTicks);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Running Time:");
        Console.WriteLine("Iteration: {0} ({1} avg)", 
                          TimeSpan.FromTicks(loop.Sum()),
                          TimeSpan.FromTicks((int)loop.Average()));
        Console.WriteLine("Recursion: {0} ({1} avg)", 
                          TimeSpan.FromTicks(recr.Sum()),
                          TimeSpan.FromTicks((int)recr.Average()));
        Console.WriteLine("Standard : {0} ({1} avg)", 
                          TimeSpan.FromTicks(std.Sum()),
                          TimeSpan.FromTicks((int)std.Average()));

        double lSum = loop.Sum();
        double rSum = recr.Sum();
        double sSum = std.Sum();

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Ratios: \n" +
                          "     | Iter | Rec  | Std \n" +
                          "-----+------+------+-----");
        foreach (var div in new[] { new {n = "Iter", t = lSum}, 
                                    new {n = "Rec ", t = rSum},
                                    new {n = "Std ", t = sSum}})
            Console.WriteLine("{0} | {1:0.00} | {2:0.00} | {3:0.00}", 
                              div.n, lSum / div.t, rSum / div.t, sSum / div.t);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static string integerToString(int integerPassedIn)
    {
        if (integerPassedIn == 0) return "0";
        var negative = integerPassedIn < 0;
        var res = new List<char>();
        while(integerPassedIn != 0)
        {
           res.Add((char)(48 + Math.Abs(integerPassedIn % 10)));
           integerPassedIn /= 10;
        }
        res.Reverse();
        if (negative) res.Insert(0, '-');
        return new string(res.ToArray());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursion:

```
    public static string integerToString(int integerPassedIn)
    {
        ICollection<char> res = new List<char>();
        IntToStringRecusion(integerPassedIn, res);
        if (integerPassedIn < 0) res.Add('-');
        return new string(res.Reverse().ToArray()).PadLeft(1,'0');
    }

    static void IntToStringRecusion(int integerPassedIn, ICollection<char> array)
    {
        if (integerPassedIn == 0) return;
        array.Add((char)(48 + Math.Abs(integerPassedIn % 10)));
        IntToStringRecusion(integerPassedIn / 10, array);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

easy peasy:

```
string s = 5 + ""
//s = "5"
```

Comment: When you use the above method, ToString is invoked

Comment: @i dont see "ToString()" called here

Comment: C# will invoke tostring when concatenating like this