# Implementing Int64.ToString without using string

Tags: c#

I have a situation where I need to convert a long to a character array without allocating any new objects. I want to mimic what is done in long.ToString() without actually creating a string object, basically - instead the characters will be inserted into a predefined array. I feel like this should be pretty straightforward, but I can't find any examples - everything in C# uses something like ToString or String.Format, everything in C++ uses either stringstream, sprintf, or ltoa. Any ideas?

edit: For a little clarify, this is part of a critical section of frequently called code that cannot withstand garbage collection, hence I don't want to allocate additional strings. The output is actually placed into a byte array - but the receiver of this data expects a byte array of the character representation of this long, so I'm attempting to reduce garbage collection by doing the conversion to string format without allocating a new object.

Comment: Use mod and division to get the value of each digit.

Comment: please, add some code with what you have tried.

Comment: What's wrong with String?

Comment: Provide an example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Alexandre I'm not exactly sure what you want, I already stated the solutions that I've found that "work" but don't fit the scenario. For example - string converted = myLong.ToString(); // This works but creates a string object which is bad

Comment: You can use a static field if you think the memory allocation is causing performance problems. Or whydo you think that ToString wouldn't work in your case?

Comment: @cadrell0 Can't allocate new objects here.

Comment: @PMF This call is made very frequently. Reusing a static string would still result in a new string being created and thrown away every time. Not acceptable in this scenario.

Comment: Follow this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17575375/how-do-i-convert-an-int-to-a-string-in-c-sharp-without-using-tostring It might be helpful for you

Comment: @gypsyCoder - good link - exactly what OP asks (should be trivial to convert from `Int32` to `Int64`) - proposing as duplicate.

Comment: @gypsyCoder Thank you - I tried searching for int to char array but couldn't find anything relevant. That should do it.

Comment: Note, declaring an array will make an object that needs to be garbage collected.  Also, the built in implementation of `ToString` happens in native CLR code.  That plus garbage collection will probably be much faster than anything your write yourself.

Comment: Declaring the array does indeed create an object - but only once, during initialization, as opposed to every time the method is called. While I don't doubt the CLR code is fast, I've already identified excessive garbage collection as a bottleneck and per profiling, this method is one of the biggest allocators of memory that gets GC'd.

Comment: You can still use a static _member_ Array in the class where the method is. That will be created only once. You'll need to manually convert from int to string, but that's not a big deal (see the post by Slaks). Downside of a static Array is that your code will no longer be thread safe. If that is required, use ThreadLocal<T> to create one array per thread.

Comment: Sure - perhaps I misunderstood your first comment, my plan was to use a static char array and simply update it with the method noted by SLaks and gypsyCoder. I just meant I couldn't use a string or ToString, because due to their immutable nature, a new object would be created every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @SLaks for the idea and @gypsoCoder for pointing me to a related answer. This does the trick:

```
  private static byte[] chars = new byte[] { (byte)'0', (byte)'1', (byte)'2', (byte)'3', (byte)'4', (byte)'5', (byte)'6', (byte)'7', (byte)'8', (byte)'9' };

  /// <summary>
  /// Converts a long to a byte, in string format
  /// 
  /// This method essentially performs the same operation as ToString, with the output being a byte array,
  /// rather than a string
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="val">long integer input, with as many or fewer digits as the output buffer length</param>
  /// <param name="longBuffer">output buffer</param>
  private void ConvertLong(long val, byte[] longBuffer)
  {
     // The buffer must be large enough to hold the output

     long limit = (long)Math.Pow(10, longBuffer.Length - 1);
     if (val >= limit * 10)
     {
        throw new ArgumentException("Value will not fit in output buffer");
     }

     // Note: Depending on your output expectation, you may do something different to initialize the data here.
     // My expectation was that the string would be at the "front" in string format, e.g. the end of the array, with '0' in any extra space

     int bufferIndex = 1;
     for (long longIndex = limit; longIndex > val; longIndex /= 10)
     {
        longBuffer[longBuffer.Length - bufferIndex] = 0;
        ++bufferIndex;
     }

     // Finally, loop through the digits of the input, converting them from a static buffer of byte values

     while (val > 0)
     {
        longBuffer[longBuffer.Length - bufferIndex] = chars[val % 10];
        val /= 10;
        ++bufferIndex;
     }
  }
```

I should note that this only accepts positive numbers and doesn't do any validation of that or anything else. Just a basic algorithm to accomplish the goal of converting a long to a string to a byte array without allocating any strings.