# How int + string becomes string?

Tags: c#, .net, obfuscation

I came across a strange way to implement `ToString()` and I am wondering how it works:

```
public string tostr(int n) 
{
    string s = "";
    foreach (char c in n-- + "") {  //<------HOW IS THIS POSSIBLE ?
        s = s + c;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Is the iterator assuming the size of a `char`?

Comment: I hope this is not production code...

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17575375/how-do-i-convert-an-int-to-a-string-in-c-sharp-without-using-tostring

Comment: This is a common Code Golf trick, it shouldn't be used in production code though because, as you saw, it leads to confusion

Comment: Small offtop - is it just `n.ToString()`?

Comment: @LmTinyToon no it would be `n.ToString();` `n = n - 1;` because `n--` is a post decrement and assigns the value back to `n`.

Comment: What's the point of post-decrementing here? Why not just `n + ""`?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder, of yes, I used pre decrement (I edited comment). thanks

Comment: `the iterator assumes the size of a char?`, well, I haven't the slightest clue about C#, but in C, the size of a char is always 1, by definition.

Comment: @vaxquis `n + ""` works for me.

Comment: BTW, why not just public string tostr(int n) { return "" + n; } ???

Comment: @xehpuk hell, you're 100% right... it wasn't Java. I can't recall *where* did I see that asymmetric `+`, but I'm *kind of sure* I've seen it somewhere...

Comment: @JasonP so what exactly do you except from bounty? There are so many answers here already.

Answer (score 19):

It calls the [`String.Concat(object, object)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbseaaft.aspx) method implicitly, which concatenates the string representations of two specified **objects**:

```
string result = String.Concat("", n--);
```

The `String.Concat(object, object)` method then calls `String.Concat(string, string)`. To read the `Concat`'s source and check it in depth, first go here: [String.cs source code in C# .NET](http://www.dotnetframework.org/Search.aspx) and then in that page in the search `TextBox` type `String` and then click on the `String.cs` link in the results to go to the *String.cs source code in C# .NET* page and check the `Concat` method.

This is the method definition:

```
public static String Concat(Object arg0, Object arg1) 
{ 
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<string>() != null);
    Contract.EndContractBlock(); 

    if (arg0 == null)
    { 
        arg0 = String.Empty;
    }

    if (arg1==null) 
    { 
        arg1 = String.Empty;
    } 
    return Concat(arg0.ToString(), arg1.ToString()); 
}
```

As you see this calls `public static String Concat(String str0, String str1)` method finally:

```
public static String Concat(String str0, String str1) 
{
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<string>() != null);
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<string>().Length ==
        (str0 == null ? 0 : str0.Length) + 
        (str1 == null ? 0 : str1.Length));
    Contract.EndContractBlock(); 

    if (IsNullOrEmpty(str0)) {
        if (IsNullOrEmpty(str1)) { 
            return String.Empty;
        }
        return str1;
    } 

    if (IsNullOrEmpty(str1)) { 
        return str0; 
    }

    int str0Length = str0.Length;

    String result = FastAllocateString(str0Length + str1.Length);

    FillStringChecked(result, 0,        str0);
    FillStringChecked(result, str0Length, str1); 

    return result;
}
```

And this is the underlying IL, by [Ildasm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ildasm-exe-il-disassembler):

```
.method public hidebysig instance string 
        tostr(int32 n) cil managed
{
  // Code size       74 (0x4a)
  .maxstack  3
  .locals init ([0] string s,
           [1] string V_1,
           [2] int32 V_2,
           [3] char c,
           [4] string V_4)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldstr      ""
  IL_0006:  stloc.0
  IL_0007:  nop
  IL_0008:  ldarg.1
  IL_0009:  dup
  IL_000a:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_000b:  sub
  IL_000c:  starg.s    n
  IL_000e:  box        [mscorlib]System.Int32
  IL_0013:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(object)
  IL_0018:  stloc.1
  IL_0019:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_001a:  stloc.2
  IL_001b:  br.s       IL_0039
  IL_001d:  ldloc.1
  IL_001e:  ldloc.2
  IL_001f:  callvirt   instance char [mscorlib]System.String::get_Chars(int32)
  IL_0024:  stloc.3
  IL_0025:  nop
  IL_0026:  ldloc.0
  IL_0027:  ldloca.s   c
  IL_0029:  call       instance string [mscorlib]System.Char::ToString()
  IL_002e:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(string,
                                                              string)
  IL_0033:  stloc.0
  IL_0034:  nop
  IL_0035:  ldloc.2
  IL_0036:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0037:  add
  IL_0038:  stloc.2
  IL_0039:  ldloc.2
  IL_003a:  ldloc.1
  IL_003b:  callvirt   instance int32 [mscorlib]System.String::get_Length()
  IL_0040:  blt.s      IL_001d
  IL_0042:  ldloc.0
  IL_0043:  stloc.s    V_4
  IL_0045:  br.s       IL_0047
  IL_0047:  ldloc.s    V_4
  IL_0049:  ret
}// end of method tostr
```

Comment: I've always considered the "magic" behind the `+` string operator a bad design. The operator doesn't really exist, the compiler does some magic and calls `Concat`. I find it far from intuitive that `1 + s` should implicitly convert a number into a string, this is any easy pifall to fall into, specally for novice programmers. `string.Concat(1, s)` should have been the only option, and anything that is not `string + string` should have been a compile time error.

Comment: @InBetween What does it mean for an operator to "exist"? If `1+1` called (hypothetically) `Number.Add(1, 1)`, would that be a bad design?

Comment: @immibis it means that there is no `+` operator defined in `string`. The compiler generates specific code for string concatenation via `+`, it's not an overload implemented in the class.

Comment: @InBetween Oh right, I forgot C# has operator overloading.

Comment: @InBetween - There's no + operator defined for int32 either.  It's a "built-in".  String is special particularly because it uses C-style Structure Hack to make it work at all in the first place.

Answer (score 15):

Explaining this "step by step" :

```
// assume the input is 1337
public string tostr(int n) {
    //line below is creating a placeholder for the result string
    string s = "";
    // below line we can split into 2 lines to explain in more detail:
    // foreach (char c in n-- + "") {
    // then value of n is concatenated with an empty string :
    // string numberString = n-- + ""; // numberString is "1337";
    // and after this line value of n will be 1336
    // which then is iterated though :
    // foreach(char c in numberString) { // meaning foreach(char c in "1337")
    foreach (char c in n-- + "") {  //<------HOW IS THIS POSSIBLE ?
        s = s + c; // here each sign of the numberString is added into the placeholder
    }
    return s; // return filled placeholder
}
```

So basically if you concatenate `string` with `int` it will automatically call `int.ToString` method and join the string together.

Comment: Note `n--` is a post decrement so `n` is converted to a string with `n + ""` and then is decremented.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder sorry, my mistake. Fixed this in updated answer.

Answer (score 10):

The type of `n--` is `int`, which gets converted to `string` by using `+` to concatenate it with `""`, which is of type `string`. Furthermore, `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`, over which the actual iteration with `foreach` takes place.

Answer (score 6):

This code looks incomprehensible because its the outcome of what I consider an awful design choice in the language.

The `+` operator doesn't really exist in `string`. If you look at the reference source, or the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx), the only declared operators for `string` are `==` and `!=`.

What really happens is that the compiler pulls one of its magic tricks, and converts the `+` operator into a call to the static method `string.Concat`.

Now if you happened to encounter `foreach (char c in string.Concat(n--, ""))` you'd probably understand the code much better, because the intent is *clear*: I want to concatenate two objects as strings and then enumerate the `char`s that make up the resulting string.

When you read `n-- + ""` that intent is far from clear, and its worse if you happen to have `n-- + s` (`s` being a `string`).

The compiler in both cases decides that you want to concatenate the arguments as strings and automatically maps this call to `string.Concat(object, object)`. One of C#'s tenants is that, unless the intent of the coder is clear, wave a red flag and ask the coder to clarify his intent. In this particular case, that tenant is violated completely.

IMHO, anything that isn't a `string + string` should have been a compile time error, but that train passed along many many years ago.

Comment: Back in the good old days - the "Golden Era" of computers - aweful meant awesome.

Comment: There is one more step you're obviating, it is that both parameter of Concat get their ToString called, so the n-- will become (n--).ToString()

Comment: It's worth noting that the compiler combines a long series of "+" operations on strings into a single Concat call.  Presumably the design team saw that this was a very common way of developers constructing strings.  If it were implemented as a standard operator, it would need to perform each Concat separately, which is a bit wasteful since it creates a bunch of intermediate string instances.  Arguably it shouldn't exist any more due to string interpolation, but it'll now be around for backwards compatibility.

Comment: @DanBryant yes, I'm not saying it isn't useful, I just think that the arguments should all be strings. Explicitly having to call  `ToString` isn't that onerous.

Answer (score 1):

To break down your code to show why it happens...

```
foreach(char c in n-- + "")
```

using the `+` operator with a string as one of the operands will convert the result to a string regardless of what the other primitive operand was, as long as it had an implementation of +. In doing so, n participates in the `string.Concat` method as you can see from the following screenshot of the Autos debug window...

[image: Autos window showing identifier values]

I called the method with "34" as you can infer. The loop identifier in there is defined as `char c` and is going through a string. This works because `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>` as you can see from the screenshot of the result of "Go to definition" of the string type:

[image: Result of right clicking string type and going to definition]

So from that point, it works the same as if you were iterating through any other list/array... or more accurately, IEnumerable with `foreach` and gets each individual `char`. `n` in the mean time has been changed to `n-- // 33 in my case`. At this point, the value of `n` is inconsequential since you are iterating through the result of the expression `n-- + ""`. It may as well have been `n++` and you would get the same result.

The line `s = s + c;` should be pretty self explanatory and just in case it isn't, each char you pull from the temporary string result of `n-- + ""` is appended to your empty (in the beginning) `string s = "";`. It results in a string because as mentioned before `+` with a string involved will result in a string. Once you are done going through all the chars, it returns the string representation.

Comment: The part about `char` being implicitly convertible to `int` is completely irrelevant here. The code converts an `int` to `string` and then iterates over the characters... at no point is any `char` being implicitly convert to `int`. The other answers are clearer, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for the feedback. I have removed the section on char/int. I thought it would have been helpful since I was also going to talk about string being an `IEnumerable<char>`

Answer (score 0):

I've used ReSharper to convert the function to Linq statements which may help some people understand what's going (or just confuse people even more).

```
public string tostrLinq(int n)
{
    return string.Concat(n--, "").Aggregate("", (string current, char c) => current + c);
}
```

As others have already stated, basically the inputted `int` is concatenated with an empty `string` which basically gives you a string representation of the the `int`. As `string` implements `IEnumerable`, the `foreach` loop breaks up the string into a `char[]`, giving each character of the string on each iteration. The loop body just then joins the characters back together as a string through concatenating each `char`.

So for example, given input of `5423`, it gets converted to `"5423"`, and then broken up into `"5"`, `"4"`, `"2"`, `"3"` and finally stitched back to `"5423"`.

Now the part that really hurt my head for a while was the `n--`. If this decrements the `int`, then why don't we get `"5422"` returned instead? This wasn't clear to me until after I read the [MSDN Article: Increment (++) and Decrement (--) Operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzcawzfw(v=vs.100).aspx)

> The increment and decrement operators are used as a shortcut to modify
> the value stored in a variable and access that value. Either operator
> may be used in a prefix or postfix syntax.
>
> ```
>  If         | Equivalent Action | Return value
> =====================================
> ++variable | variable += 1     | value of variable after incrementing
> variable++ | variable += 1     | value of variable before incrementing
> --variable | variable -= 1     | value of variable after decrementing
> variable-- | variable -= 1     | value of variable before decrementing
> ```

So because the decrement operator is applied at the end to `n`, the value of `n` is read and used by `string.Concat` before `n` is decremented by 1.

I.e. `string.Concat(n--,"")` is going to give the same output as `string.Contact(n, ""); n = n - 1;`.

So to get `"5422"` we would change it to `string.Concat(--n, "")` so that `n` is decrement first before it is passed to `string.Contact`.

**TL;DR; The function is a round about way of doing `n.ToString()`**

Interestingly, I also used ReSharper to convert it to a `for` loop but the function no longer works as `n` is decremented on each iteration of the for loop, unlike the `foreach` loop:

```
public string tostrFor(int n)
{
    string s = "";
    for (int index = 0; index < string.Concat(n--, "").Length; index++)
    {
        char c = string.Concat(n--, "")[index];
        s = s + c;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> String concatenation:
>
> ```
> …
> string operator +(object x, string y);
> ```
>
> The binary `+` operator performs string concatenation when one or both
>   operands are of type string. If an operand of string concatenation is
>   null, an empty string is substituted. Otherwise, **any non-string
>   operand is converted to its string representation by invoking the
>   virtual `ToString` method inherited from type `object`.** If `ToString`
>   returns `null`, an empty string is substituted.
>   — [ECMA-334](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf), page 201.

So, `n.ToString()` is called. Everything else in the method is just decomposing and recomposing the result to no effect.

It could have been written as:

```
public string tostr(int n) => n.ToString();
```

But, why?

Answer (score 0):

Since `n--` is a post decrement the value of n is only changed after the concatenation. so essentially it is doing nothing at all. it could have simply been

```
foreach (char c in n + "")
```

or

```
foreach (char c in (n++) + "")
```

either way nothing changes. the original value gets iterated