# Difference between converting integer to string "" +1 and 1.ToString()

Tags: c#, winforms, converters

**What is the difference when I convert integer to string like this way:**

```
string str = "" + 1;
```

**And**

```
string str =1.ToString();
```

Comment: Why not just write: `"1"`

Comment: I know i can write it like this "1" , but i asking maybe im use variable ,like int number = 1 * number2 ; .... and do that "" + number ... :)

Comment: The first is implicit, the second is explicit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first method is equivalent to `string str = "" + 1.ToString();` and uses 2 intermediate strings before producing the result. That amounts to 3 strings total: an empty string, "1", and the result of the concatenation, which is also "1".

The second method doesn't use any intermediate string. It's also more readable and clearly expresses your intent (which is to convert the integer into a string).

Answer (score 1):

With `ToString()` you assign a return value of the method. By using `"" + 1` the `ToString()` method is called by the CLR.

See [Automatic .ToString()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759343/automatic-tostring)

Answer (score 0):

`int.ToString()` is **the** tool for converting an integer into a string.

However, the C# allows you not to call this method when concatenating strings via **plus operator**, and the framework calls `.ToString()` instead of you.